# Array of Bytes to an URL encoded in JavaScript for ImageJ

Tags: javascript, byte, urlencode, imagej, fiji

I need too convert my array of bytes (an image) to an URL encoded so it can be interpreted by my distant server then after treatment, will re-encode it and send back to the user.

This is for setting up a server (cloud) on which the hosted model of deep Learning will get the image treated by the user (using FiJi (imageJ) at laboratories). it will remove noises (Poisson and Gaussian) and user will receive his stack directly from server, avoiding them to install heavy stuff on their computer.

```
importClass(Packages.ij.IJ);
importClass(java.awt.image.BufferedImage);
importClass(java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream);
importClass(java.io.File);
importClass(javax.imageio.ImageIO);
importClass(java.util.Base64);
importClass(java.lang.StringBuffer);

imp = IJ.getImage();

var buffered = imp.getBufferedImage();
imp.draw();
imp.getCurrentSlice();

baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write( buffered, "jpg", baos );
baos.flush();
imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
IJ.log(imageInByte[18751]);
```

So at the moment (i'm kind of new with JS So sorry about the "IJ.log(imageInByte[])" line because it was the only way to see if my bytes encoding was working correcly.

I'm now struggling to find a way to have this "imageInByte" converted to an URL so my next step will be to setup the server so he can get this URL, decode it, having the 8-bit image, do his job to remove noises on the picture (microscopes stacks) , recode it into bytes then URL and resend it to the Customer via ImageJ Plugin and enjoy the clean image without installing the whole model on localhost ...

I have no idea how to proceed since everything I found are pure Java or Web programming and i'm writing a FiJi script
(excuse my lvl I'm not enough familiar for passing from a language to another since i've found solutions but for unsimilar problems and  for PLSQL or C++)

I'd usually go with "btoa" then "atob" but my fiji console return me "not defined" i've imported many buffering class but it wont be "defined" for it...

Edit : alternate solution would be to get the same code (i don't know how to import these java libraries as Jython) so I can have same result (bytes array of the image) and making it an encoded URL seems much more easy in Python so i'll be open to any help about translating this into python too !

Answer (score 0):

So after realizing things are getting harder with JS, I swapped my code to python (was easy thanks to Jython env)

I went further in my problem so I'll post in python

answer : it's impossible to convert a byte of array to an URL encoded or with a toString in JS.

thanks again for your precious help.